# How can I consume ASP.NET Web API using XCode Swift and Set json array to UITableView

Tags: xcode, asp.net-web-api

I want to call `ASP.NET` `Web API` which returns `json` `array` and then i want to set its returned `array` to `UITableView`

Comment: It would help if you edited the post and attached your code so far.